# How to reload TreeStore?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have nestedlist with treestore. While loading first time the store is loaded perfectly and list is being displayed according to the store. When i click refresh button , my treestore should get reloaded with new data (with same data model as the first time) and nested list also need to be reloaded with new set of data.

Below is my treestore definition

```
rightPaneStoreData = getFolderListData();

rightPaneStore =new Ext.data.TreeStore({

   autoLoad:false,

   model: 'FIMT.models.rightPaneModel',

   root: rightPaneStoreData,
   proxy: {

   type: 'memory',

   reader: {

       type: 'tree',
       root: 'items'
       }

   },
   listeners: {
       datachanged: function(records){
           alert("datachanged");
           }
   }

   });

rightPaneStore.load();
```

In Ext.data.JsonStore i have accomplished the same using store.loaddata() method. But i couldnt find loaddata() method for TreeStore.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 9):

This is working for me.  I'm using MVC and this code is called in my controller.

```
treeStore.getRootNode().removeAll();
treeStore.load();
```

Comment: treeStore.getRootNode().removeAll(); is what I exactly needed in order to avoid simultaneous ajax calls made for each node when  treeStore.load(); is called

Comment: This is working but, do you have any idea why it is taking too much time to remove records from my treestore

Answer (score 0):

The `TreePanel` doesn't have a store like a `JsonStore`. It automatically shows all nodes, and reloads when needed.

In case your rootNode (`rightPaneStoreData`) is an `AsyncTreeNode` (loaded through AJAX), you can use:

`rightPaneStoreData.reload()`
(because `rightPaneStoreData` is your root node).

or alternatively (more generic):
`tree.root.reload();`
(where tree is a reference to your tree)

If it isn't an `ASyncTreeNode`, you'll have to do it manually.
Call your `getFolderListData()` function again, and assign the new root to the tree. (`tree.setRootNode()`)

Comment: Are there any errors on your console? (Chrome Devtools / Firefox Firebug?)

Comment: Yes in chrome, it says reload() is not available for both my rightpanestoredata reference & treestore reference.

Comment: I automatically guessed you we're using an AJAX-based tree (ASyncTreeNode). If you manually create your tree on the client side (and not through a `dataUrl`), you'll have to manually update/reload your tree too.

Comment: S, I'm not loading the data store from url. Im loading treestore  manually. Kindly give me sample how to manually update or reload the treestore.

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the tree by using a memory proxy. See the answer in [How to update the Nested List/Tree Store in Sencha Touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737806/how-to-update-the-nested-list-tree-store-in-sencha-touch)

Answer (score 0):

```
treeStore.getRootNode().removeAll();
treeStore.setRootNode({
  id: rootNodeId,
  text: 'root'
  // other configs in root
});
// if you had non-standard children loads, then you would need to call:
treeStore.getProxy().load();
// if you had non-standard children loads, and you had params in your load, then you would need to call:
treeStore.getProxy().load({
  params: {
    node: rootNodeId
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Remove all current children if clear on load not set 
if (!treeStore.clearOnLoad) { 
    record.removeAll(); 
} 

// Call load, refreshing our view when done... 
var viewRefresher = function() { 
    view.refresh(); 
}; 

treeStore.load({ 
    node: record, 
    callback: viewRefresher 
});
```